# Triple integration in python for array like inputs

Tags: python

Starting from a covariance matrix and mean values (OMEGA), for a multivariate gaussian distribution (3x3), I want to integrate a the 3-dim function in the range [0,Inf].

I am adequate with MATLAB and made effort to compute this integral. Please refer to [this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778975/nested-int-not-giving-relevant-answers?noredirect=1#comment74599716_43778975).

It appears that the integral is difficult to solve. I would, therefore, want to try python to get the desired answer.

The exercise is to figure out the normalizing constant (desired answer) of the above integration.

COVAR = `

```
1.0e-11 *

  0.0268   -0.0518    0.0228
 -0.0518    0.1020   -0.0472
  0.0228   -0.0472    0.0337
```

OMEGA = `

```
1.0e-06 *

-0.0516    0.1902   -0.1424
```

Thank you in advance.

`

Comment: Changing languages from matlab to python or vice versa won't help you there. I don't have the formula for the three dimensional gaussian distribution handy, but I can tell you that in it's textbook form the triple integral from -inf to +inf in all 3 coordinates will be exactly 1. Compare the coefficients of your equation with the one for which the integral is one, and you get the normalizing constant without calculating any integral.

Comment: Dear Mars, thank you for your comments. Actually, I roughly know the answer to the integral, 1/8. But I want to PLOT the 3-dim distribution so that I can make the contour plots(among each pair) thereafter. Moreover, this can be further marginalized to give one dimension distribution for each parameter. I intend to estimate the parameters when the distribution is restricted only to the positive quadrant.